# MySQL sum with negative decimals

Tags: mysql, sum, negative-number, decimal

I have a qty column in my table, and i'm trying to sum the values.  The field type is varchar(20).  The sum of qty below should add up to exactly 0. It's a mix of negative and positive decimals.

[exhibit A](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/7ad76d81-e10d-4783-93f3-84f4c63a054c/7fa5de1f697f6298bbe571066b833235) (screenshot)

When i perform the sum below, i'm getting a tonne of decimals instead of 0.  I'm assuming this is a datatype issue. What's the best way to work around this?

[exhibit B](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/41fb8878-55f3-4d8a-958d-c10a5b306e4d/9468e18a2c10b2c34f7428ed015f44be) (screenshot)

Comment: your screenshots are restricted. please edit the question and post the sample data and table structure.

Comment: @bluefeet - i updated the links to the images, should work now.

Comment: @drschultz what is the datatype of `qty`?

Comment: Why are you storing numeric values in a character column?

Comment: @ianzz i didn't create the schema, i have to work with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be storing numeric data as a string but if you do, then you will need to `cast()` it to apply a `SUM()` aggregate to it:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(yourcolumn AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) 
FROM yourtable
```

So your query will be:

```
select sum(cast(qty as DECIMAL(10, 2)))
from inventory i
where i.refDocNum = 485
  and i.refApp = 'WO'
  and i.type in (20, 21)
```

Comment: Note that casting to `DECIMAL` without specifying precision will produce integer values only.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks, i hear what you're saying about storing it as a string, but this was before my time on this project.